# Regenerate cython extension with distutils

Tags: python, cython, distutils

I have a cython file that generates a different `.c` file depending on whether it's been compiled for python 2 or python 3.  That is:

```
from .mp_utils import PY3

if PY3:
    builtin = (int, float, str, complex)
else:
    builtin = (int, float, str, long, complex, file)
```

with `mp_utils` having this:

```
PY3 = sys.version > '3'
```

This extension is built by distutils.  `setup.py` has:

```
getsize = Extension(
    'memprof.getsize',
    sources=['memprof/getsize.pyx']
)

setup(
    # [...]
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=[getsize],
)
```

However, cython is not aware that it has to rebuild the `.c` on every invocation of `python setup.py install`:

```
# python3 setup.py test
running test
running egg_info
writing dependency_links to memprof.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to memprof.egg-info/requires.txt
writing memprof.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to memprof.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'memprof.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'memprof.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
skipping 'memprof/getsize.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'memprof.getsize' extension
[...]
```

This is wrong, `memprof/getsize.c` is not up to date, it's the `getsize.c` built for the python 2 version.  It has to be rebuilt.  How can I tell distutils (or cython) that it has to regenerate the `.c` file on every invocation?

I know that I can touch `memprof/getsize.pyx` or just delete `memprof/getsize.c` by hand but you have to remember to do that and it's not what I'm looking for.  I want something that when I do python3 setup.py install it installs the right thing no matter what I built before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup.py` options can be defined in a `setup.cfg` file.

Therefore, something like this in your `setup.cfg`:

```
[build_ext]
force=1
```

will force the compilation each time.